# EmberJS: How to position the application template

Tags: ember.js

I'm running into a problem. I need `App.rootElement = "body"`, because views and components will be used all over the place. I do not want to put the entire page in a handlebars template, due to SEO and other concerns. The main application template will exist somewhere in the center of the page:

```
<h1>Header markup</h1>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Application Template</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>

<h1>Footer markup</g1>
```

However, when the page is rendered, this template is appended to the end of the body, instead of staying where the template script has been placed. (see [jsbin exmaple](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/voveqaquka/4/edit)) Is there any way to tell Ember to render the application template where it is in the markup?

One hacky solution I've found is to manually move the containing element in `didInsertElement`, but that seems a little heavy handed and not something that would be considered a best practice. (see [jsbin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/voveqaquka/5/edit))

Answer (score 0):

The script tag doesn't have anything to do with placement, if you want it to live somewhere create a div tag, id it, and change the rootElement to that div tag.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  <h2>Application Template</h2>

  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

...

```
<h1>Header markup</h1>
<div id='foo'></div>
<h1>Footer markup</h1>

App.rootElement = '#foo';
```

Comment: That's just the problem. The rootElement needs to surround the entire page, but I cannot put the entire page in a handlebars template. If I could have the rootElement localized to that one spot AND place views and components outside it without Ember complaining, it would work.